# how to install CTI adapters for salesforce

Tags: appexchange, opencti, cti

can any one provide me the links how to install CTI Adapters for salesforce and pricing list.

Can i have Free adapters for demo purpose for 30 days.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange veeru. While this community is infact here to help and gather knowledge, we're a lot better at answering very clear and specific questions which can be solved with a single answer.  Questions which are very broad or subjective are better asked in other platforms.

Comment: this might help you http://bytesofcode.hubpages.com/hub/Salesforce-CTI-integration-setting-up-Open-CTI-sample-application

Answer (score 4):

CTI Adapters are specific to your phone system and are supplied by the company that makes your phone system or a third party. Look at the AppExchange for some vendors to research: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=cti